Error: can't find collector after installing minihtcondor as root
I installed htcondor as root following the instructions here on Rocky Linux 9.
This is a single machine installation. Following the instructions, I am trying to check if the installation finished successfully with condor_status, which is giving me Error: can't find collector. However, condor_q gives me what is desired.
So any jobs submitted remain IDLE indefinitely. Unfortunately, the instructions do no seem to include a way to overcome the problem.
(Extra: Installation by a user following this works fine.)
Thanks in advance.
